# How can I get data from my repository, I can't fetch the data I stored

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I stored data into firebase using my repository and also the data is stored in my postdata object. I don't know how to get the data from the postdata object onto the app. What I mean by that is that the data should be stored into the postdata object but I don't know how to get the information.
**Here is my postdata object**

```
class PostData with ChangeNotifier{
  int likesCount;
  String imageLink;
  List likes;
  int timestamp;
  String postersName;
  String postersId;
  String postersImageUrl;
  List postSavedByUsers;
  String title;
  String id;
  String description;
  double price;
  String imageUrl;
  String productCategoryName;
  String brand;
  bool isPopular;
  String productId;


  PostData(

      int likesCount,
      List likes,
      int timestamp,

      String postersName,
      String postersId,
      String postersImageUrl,
      String postersRole,
      List postSavedByUsers,
  String title,
  String id,
  String description,
  double price,
  String imageUrl,
  String productCategoryName,
  String brand,
  bool isPopular,
  String productId,

  ) {

    this.likesCount = likesCount;
    this.imageLink = imageLink;
    this.likes = likes;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;

    this.postersName = postersName;
    this.postersId = postersId;
    this.postersImageUrl = postersImageUrl;
    this.postSavedByUsers = postSavedByUsers;
    this.title = title;
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.productCategoryName = productCategoryName;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.isPopular = isPopular;
    this.productId=productId;
  }

  PostData.zero();

  PostData mapToObject(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return PostData(

        map["likes_count"],

        map["likes"],
        map["timestamp"],

        map["posters_name"],
        map["posters_id"],
        map["posters_image_url"],
        map["posters_role"],
        map["post_saved"],
        map["title"],
        map["id"],
        map["description"],
        map["price"],
        map["imageUrl"],
        map["productCategoryName"],
        map["brand"],
        map["isPopular"],
      map["productId"],
    );
  }

  List<PostData> forArrayToObject(
      List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> data) {
    List<PostData> postListData = [];
    for (var object in data) {
      postListData.add(mapToObject(object.data()));
    }
    return postListData;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {

      "likes_count": this.likesCount,
      "image_link": this.imageLink,
      "likes": this.likes,
      "posters_name": this.postersName,
      "posters_id": this.postersId,
      "posters_image_url": this.postersImageUrl,
      "post_saved": this.postSavedByUsers,
      "title": this.title,
      "id": this.id,
      "timestamp": this.timestamp,


      "description": this.description,
      "price": this.price,
      "imageUrl": this.imageUrl,
      "productCategoryName": this.productCategoryName,
      "brand": this.brand,
      "isPopular": this.isPopular,
      "productId": this.productId

    };
    return map;
  }
}
```

**Here is my repository**

```
class AddPostRepository {
  Future<void> postDataToFireStore(PostData data) async {
    await firebaseFirestore
        .collection("post")
        .doc(data.timestamp.toString())
        .set(data.toMap());

    await firebaseFirestore
        .collection("user")
        .doc(data.postersId)
        .update({"posts_count": FieldValue.increment(1)});
  }
}
```

**Here is my fetch products function**

```
 Future<void> fetchProducts() async {
    print('Fetch method is called');
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('post')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot productsSnapshot) {
      _products = [];
      productsSnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
        // print('element.get(productBrand), ${element.get('productBrand')}');
        _products.insert(
          0,
          PostData(

          0,

        [],
            Timestamp.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,

        name,
        token,
        image,
        "member",
        [],
        "",
        "",
        "",
        4,
        "",
        "",
        "",
        true,
            ""
        ),);
      });
    });
  }
```

All the data is successfully stored onto firebase however, I don't know how to get the fetch products to work. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWKeO.png)

Here is the image I am getting on my emulator showing that I can't load the data from firebase using my fetch products function. I don't know how to get it to work. I can't embed images since I don't have enogugh points but here is the link. If anyone needs more, I can provide more info. My problem is that the postdata I stored won't show when I try to call it. It perfectly stores in firebase though. I have no problem with storing info, I just can't fetch the information I stored.

Answer (score 0):

Change your fetchProducts function to this.

```
Future<void> fetchProducts() async {
  print('Fetch method is called');
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('post')
      .withConverter<PostData>(
        fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => PostData.fromFirestore(snapshot),
        toFirestore: (data, _) => data.toMap(),
      )
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    // List<PostData> _products;
    _products = snapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
    // _products should contain all your products.
  });
}
```

add this to your PostData object:

```
factory PostData.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
  Map<String, dynamic> json = snapshot.data();
  json['id'] = snapshot.id;
  // UPDATED
  // return mapToObject(json);
  return PostData(
    json["likes_count"],
    json["likes"],
    json["timestamp"],
    json["posters_name"],
    json["posters_id"],
    json["posters_image_url"],
    json["posters_role"],
    json["post_saved"],
    json["title"],
    json["id"],
    json["description"],
    json["price"],
    json["imageUrl"],
    json["productCategoryName"],
    json["brand"],
    json["isPopular"],
    json["productId"],
  );
}
```

More update. Ideally, this is how your model should look like.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PostData with ChangeNotifier {
  int likesCount;
  String imageLink;
  List likes;
  int timestamp;
  String postersName;
  String postersId;
  String postersImageUrl;
  List postSavedByUsers;
  String title;
  String id;
  String description;
  double price;
  String imageUrl;
  String productCategoryName;
  String brand;
  bool isPopular;
  String productId;

  PostData({
    this.likesCount,
    this.imageLink,
    this.likes,
    this.timestamp,
    this.postersName,
    this.postersId,
    this.postersImageUrl,
    this.postSavedByUsers,
    this.title,
    this.id,
    this.description,
    this.price,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.productCategoryName,
    this.brand,
    this.isPopular,
    this.productId,
  });

  // PostData.zero();

  // formerly mapToObject
  factory PostData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return PostData(
      likesCount: map["likes_count"],
      likes: map["likes"],
      timestamp: map["timestamp"],
      postersName: map["posters_name"],
      postersId: map["posters_id"],
      postersImageUrl: map["posters_image_url"],
      // TODO: NO PROPERTY CALLED postersRole
      // postersRole: map["posters_role"],
      postSavedByUsers: map["post_saved"],
      title: map["title"],
      id: map["id"],
      description: map["description"],
      price: map["price"],
      imageUrl: map["imageUrl"],
      productCategoryName: map["productCategoryName"],
      brand: map["brand"],
      isPopular: map["isPopular"],
      productId: map["productId"],
    );
  }

  // List<PostData> forArrayToObject(
  //     List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> docs) {
  //   return docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
  // }

  // formerly toMap() {
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      "likes_count": this.likesCount,
      "image_link": this.imageLink,
      "likes": this.likes,
      "posters_name": this.postersName,
      "posters_id": this.postersId,
      "posters_image_url": this.postersImageUrl,
      "post_saved": this.postSavedByUsers,
      "title": this.title,
      "id": this.id,
      "timestamp": this.timestamp,
      "description": this.description,
      "price": this.price,
      "imageUrl": this.imageUrl,
      "productCategoryName": this.productCategoryName,
      "brand": this.brand,
      "isPopular": this.isPopular,
      "productId": this.productId
    };
    return map;
  }

  factory PostData.fromFirestore(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    Map<String, dynamic> json = snapshot.data();
    json['id'] = snapshot.id;
    return PostData.fromJson(json);
  }
}

// read about this package json_annotation and use it. It will make your models
// transformations easier
```

Then, to get the _products data (as you asked in your comment), you can do things like:

```
_products = snapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
// to loop through the products, you can do this
for (var product in _products) {
  print(product);
  print(product.likesCount); // you can fetch other PostData attributes like this
  print(product.postersName);
  // you can do whatever you like for each product here.
}
```

Comment: Hi, when I try to plug in the factory PostData.fromFirestore, it gives me an error at mapToObject, the error being "Instance members can't be accessed from a factory constructor."

Comment: The fetch products function didn't give me errors but the second post data object, when I tried to add it in, it gave me an error. Would it work if I didn't add factory PostData.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
  Map<String, dynamic> json = snapshot.data();
  json['id'] = snapshot.id;
  return mapToObject(json);
}

Comment: Your model is not ideally structured. But I have updated my answer with a workaround. Try that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for editing it, I am getting no errors but for the fetch products function, when you comment out "products should contain all your products", how would I type it in since my products attributes are in the post data.

Comment: The short answer is `for (var product in _products) print(product);`. This will print the data contained in _products. The long and better answer is in my original answer. You should use that one. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solves your query.

Comment: Hi, I tried that and got no error however, when I go onto my app, nothing came up. When I look at my console, it says fetch method is called however it also says Unhandled Exception: type 'List<Object>' is not a subtype of type and also,  Products.fetchProducts.<anonymous closure>

Comment: My problem is I can't load the data from firebase to my app using the fetch product function. The info is also stored in postdata but I don't know why it doesn't show.

Comment: Okay, did you use the full answer (the updated original answer) or short answer (the one in the comments). And what is the full error message you receive.